# Cómo descontar un porcentaje

Tags: javascript

Necesito aplicar porcentajes de descuento ya definidos, en este ejemplo cada prenda vale **450** y se agregaron **3** para dar un total de **1350**

¿Qué debería hacer para aplicar un porcentaje de descuento? por ejemplo un 25%

```js
var price = 450

var prendas = 3;

document.write(prendas * price);
```

Comment: Multiplicar el total por `0.75`, esto es más problema de matemática básica que de programación.

Answer (score 2):

Es matemáticas y depende un poco de lo que quieras. Sabes que 25% es como multilicar por 0.25 (25/100)

```
var price = 450
var prendas = 3;
document.write("Precio total sin descuento " +(prendas * price));
document.write("Descuento: " +(prendas * price * 0.25));
document.write("Precio total con descuento: " +(prendas * price * 0.75));
```

Lo del 0.75 es como hacer: **T - T · 0.25**
si sacas factor común la **T** se queda en  **T · (1 - 0.25) = T · 0.75**
Aquí **T** sería prendas*price

Answer (score 1):

al mencionar que utilizas descuentos ya definidos, puedes almacenar el porcentaje en una variable de la siguiente manera:

```
var descuento = 0.25
var price = 450;
var prendas = 3;
document.write(prendas * (price * descuento));
```

De esta manera, se esta uilizando la jerarquia de operaciones, multiplicando primero el precio por el descuento y el resultado de dicha operacion se multplica por la cantidad de prendas.